Unbatch block fails to extract agents after the release block
In my AnyLogic model, I have a factory which produces 100 Products (of class Product). The batch block packs these 100 boxes into one Inventory agent (of class Inventory). As it can be seen from the picture AnyLogic Model, the Seize block seizes one truck from the resource pool. This truck is supposed to attach batched Inventory agent from nodeShippingArea to nodeShopStorage. However, after the release block, when Inventory enters the unbatch block, the unbatch block fails to extract previous 100 products. Instead it outputs 1 agent of type Product. I assume the problem lies within the Seize/Release blocks, because when I place the unbatch block before the seize block, everything works correctly. However, I need to unbatch the inventory block after it reaches the nodeShopStorage. What can be the problem here?

just to double-check: The Batch block is batching into non-permanent batches, correct?

what happens if you just use the MoveTo block without seize/release around it? (but still between batch/unbatch)?

@Benjamin, yes I am using temporary batches in this model. However, as it turns out without Seize and Release blocks, it still gives the same problem. Only now, besides the fact that 1 inventory is not unbatched into 100 products, but only to 1, the truck is not seized from the resource pool to be used.

weird indeed, maybe send a bug request to support@anylogic.com with a simplified model that shows the issue

Are you sure that the Delay1 block (the second one) is not restricted by capacity?
